# How to see the implementation of the auto-indent procedure?

Tags: indentation

I want to inspect the lisp code that handle auto-indentation.
By "auto-indent" I mean the indentation that automatically puts the beginning of a line at the right position in files such as `.c`, `.cpp`, and `.java`.

How do I find the code?

Answer (score 2):

To query the value of a variable or function in Emacs,
you can use the default keybindings of `C-h v VARIABLE` and
`C-h f FUNCTION`, respectively.  If you're not sure what to
look for, `M-x apropos SOMETHING` will help you look for
functions and variables that contain SOMETHING in their names.

In your case, look up the *variable* `indent-line-function`,
whose docstring reads:

> Documentation:
>   Function to indent the current line.
>   This function will be called with no arguments.
>   If it is called somewhere where auto-indentation cannot be done
>   (e.g. inside a string), the function should simply return `noindent`.
>   Setting this function is all you need to make TAB indent appropriately.
>   Don't rebind TAB unless you really need to.

That variable will tell you which function to inspect.
For example, in `lisp-interaction-mode` (i.e., the default
mode in the `*scratch*` buffer), the value is `lisp-indent-line`.
The help window should be hyperlinked, and, at the top, it
will tell you:

> lisp-indent-line is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `lisp-mode.el`.
>   ...

You should be able to click on `lisp-mode.el`, and Emacs will
open up that file at the function in question.